# Is there a way to run a scheduled task on Windows XP without having to enter the username and password?

Tags: windows-xp, permissions, scheduled-tasks

I would like to setup a job without having to enter the user/pass.

Can this be done?

Comment: What kind of task are you trying to perform?

Answer (score 6):

After you set the task up, if you right click on the task and go to properties, you can check a box that says "Run only when logged on". This doesn't require a username/password.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add it with the `SYSTEM` account. This one doesn't need a password.

**Beware!** The system account has basically the same rights as the administrator, so this might be a security issue.

Answer (score 2):

[From Cameron Incoll's blog](http://cameron.incoll.org/?p=33):

Note: this is a security loophole! But I'm sure you're aware.

> Sometimes it’s handy to have a
>   scheduled task do something in Windows
>   XP. I use a couple for different
>   reasons. One is to do a weekly backup
>   of data from one disk to another, and
>   the other is to do a daily grab of the
>   TV guide from IceTV to process and
>   deliver to my Topfield PVR.
>
> Annoyingly, but probably
>   appropriately, XP doesn’t let you run
>   scheduled tasks by default without a
>   password set on the user account. This
>   is described in Microsoft knowledge
>   base article 310715.
>
> Instead of creating a password for my
>   login at home, and instead of creating
>   a ‘dummy’ account with a password just
>   for scheduled tasks, I found this:
>   Scheduled Tasks - Running Tasks
>   Without A Password.

**For XP Pro:**

Go to Start/Administrative Tools/Local Security Policy/Security Settings/Local Policies/Security Options Accounts:

Limit local account use of blank passwords to console logon only. This is enabled by
default, disable it.

**For XP Home:**

Go to Start/Run/Regedit and navigate to this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
Value name: limitblankpassworduse, Type: REG_DWORD, Data: 0 (disabled) 1 (enabled)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try System Scheduler. It is something you have to install but requires no password to run tasks. It sits in the taskbar tray and just works. I have used it in the past.

http://www.splinterware.com/products/wincron.htm

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you have to provide a user name and password. What would be the alternative: an OS in which unidentified users were running processes on a machine with no authentication?